Mac OS hotkey monitor won't react if cursor is in password reading state
I use the following code to discriminate by exit code between three hotkeys:
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

CGEventRef myCGEventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon) {

  if (type == kCGEventKeyDown) {

    CGKeyCode keycode = (CGKeyCode) CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode);
    CGEventFlags flags = CGEventGetFlags(event);

    if (keycode == 0x06 && (flags & kCGEventFlagMaskAlternate)) {
      // The Option+Z key combination was pressed
      exit(1);
    }
    if (keycode == 0x00 && (flags & kCGEventFlagMaskAlternate)) {
      // The Option+A key combination was pressed
      exit(2);
    }
    if (keycode == 0x0c && (flags & kCGEventFlagMaskAlternate)) {
      // The Option+Q key combination was pressed
      exit(3);
    }
  }
  return event;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource;

  CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionDefault, kCGEventMaskForAllEvents, myCGEventCallback, NULL);

  if (!eventTap) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't create event tap!");
    exit(255);
  }

  runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);

  CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

  CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);

  CFRunLoopRun();

  CFRelease(eventTap);
  CFRelease(runLoopSource);
  [pool release];

  exit(0);
}

It catches those hotkeys fine unless the password is asked e.g.,
$ sudo date
Password:

If a hotkey is pressed when password is expected it won't be triggered. And I need it to still be triggered. Assuming all the latest software. I tried run it as setuid, enabled Accessibility and Input monitoring but nothing works.
